# Yarn commands can't be executed in the regular way

Tags: javascript, windows, yarnpkg

When a yarn command is getting executed, it gives an security error as an unauthorized access.

```
yarn : File %FILEPATH%\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this        
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn start
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

But it can be by bypassed using the command shown below.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File '%FILEPATH%\yarn.ps1' yarn start
```

All the npm commands are working fine and the errors only occurred when executing the yarn commands. And the commands were run on windows 10 operating system. 
Is there way to execute the yarn commands in regular way? ( just executing only the command as **yarn start**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug in PowerShell

Have you installed node on your system?

try to uninstall yarn

and try to install it with the [installer](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#download-the-installer)

> This will give you a .msi file that when run will walk you through installing Yarn on Windows.
>
> If you use the installer you will first need to install Node.js.

If it does not work, you can use a command described in this link
[link](https://www.nextofwindows.com/fix-unable-to-run-yarn-in-windows-terminal-powershell)

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

[also this link could help you](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6913)

Comment: I have already installed Node and I tried as above. But still the same error occurs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NuvinduNirmana
It's seems a bug of powershell.
I think these links could help you:
1- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6913
2- https://www.nextofwindows.com/fix-unable-to-run-yarn-in-windows-terminal-powershell

Comment: It worked!! I used the command in the second [link](https://www.nextofwindows.com/fix-unable-to-run-yarn-in-windows-terminal-powershell) . Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted. @DariushStony add your comment as the answer, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @NuvinduNirmana
Tnx
Done. Now you can accept my answer as the correct answer